# Arabic Justification On CoreText

Tags: ios, arabic, core-text

I'm apple iPhone developer
I want to create application to show arabic text, I use CoreText to show my text but result is not what I want.
Between two Arabic words in justified alignment words is breaking and I want kashidas painted between two words, how can i do that? 
Please help me

Comment: Just a slight confusion here, you mean that you want kashidas instead of whitespace? Like الكتاب ـــــالأحمر or الكتاب ـــــ الأحمر? (Sorry, my Arabic is weak.) Or do you mean something else? I haven't played with kashidas on iOS, but on Mac it definitely inserts them inside of words when justifying. But you want them between the words instead? Can you give an example of the layout you want?